Getting Access Denied Error in production on uploading to AWS S3 bucket
I have an EC2 instance running that has my NodeJs backend, it was running fine until a few days, when i try to upload an image it gives me access denied error, but the same code when run on my local machine works fine.
Though I get a warning saying that I am using V2 of the aws sdk , updating to V3 of the sdk the error replicated in my local machine as well ( which works fine with V2 ) .
Below is uploading logic.
const S3 = require("aws-sdk/clients/s3")
require("dotenv").config();
const fs = require("fs");
const bucketName = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME
const region = process.env.AWS_BUCKET_REGION
const access_key = process.env.AWS_ACCESSS_KEY
const secret_key = process.env.AWS_SCERET_KEY

const s3 = new S3({
  region,
  access_key,
  secret_key
})
// upload

function uploadImage(file, name) {

  const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(file.path);

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: name, 
    Body: fileContent,
    ACL: 'public-read', 
    ContentType: 'image/jpeg', type
  };

  return s3.upload(params).promise();
}

// Upload multiple images
async function uploadImages(files) {
  const promises = [];
  if(!files || files.lenght <1){
    return [];
  }
  for (const file of files) {
    if(!file){
      return [];
    }
    const promise = uploadImage(file, file.filename);
    promises.push(promise);
  }
  return Promise.all(promises);
}

module.exports = {
  uploadImage,
  uploadImages
};

and here is my controller to upload the image
exp.AddProduct = RouterAsncErrorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    // Validate fields
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    // console.log(errors);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }
    const { colorOptions } = req.body;
    // console.log(req.files);
    const validation = validateProduct(req);
    const { image, otherimages } = req.files;
    if (validation?.failed) {
        // console.log(validation);
        removeFileFromLocal(image, otherimages);
        return res.status(422).json({
            message: validation.message
        })
    }
    // console.log(req.body, req.files);
    if (!image || image.length < 1) {
        throw new CustomError(400, "Invalid Parameters", "Invalid");
    }
    try {

        const response = await uploadImages(image);
        let otherResp;
        let other_images;
        if (otherimages?.length > 0) {
            otherResp = await uploadImages(otherimages);
            other_images = otherResp.map((image) => image.Location);
        }
        // console.log(response, otherResp);
        const image_url = response[0].Location;
        const newProd = new ProductModel({
            ...req.body, image_url, colorOptions: JSON.parse(colorOptions),
            other_images: other_images?.length > 0 ? other_images : [],
        });
        const savedPro = await newProd.save();
        // console.log(savedPro);
        removeFileFromLocal(image, otherimages);
        return res.status(201).json({
            message: 'Product added',
            product: savedPro
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        const { image, otherimages } = req.files;
        removeFileFromLocal(image, otherimages);
        next(error);
    }
});


I tried : using credentials from ~aws folder , it didn't work , credentials are all correct ( consoled them)
restarting the server same, tried upgrading to v3 of the aws sdk and changed the code for the same . ( then access denied error in local as well) , s3 bucket is public.

Please show us the IAM policy associated with the credentials you are using. Those credentials will require permission to upload to the S3 bucket.

@JohnRotenstein here it is {
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Sid": "VisualEditor0",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": [
"s3:PutObject",
"s3:GetObject",
"s3:DeleteObject"
],
"Resource": "my resource (dummy)*"
}
]
}     i don't think it has anything to do with iam roles as it is working when I run it on local

When you run it 'on local', how are you providing the credentials? When you run it on the EC2 instance, how are you providing the credentials? Typically, when running on a local machine you would provide credentials for an IAM User and when running it on an EC2 instance you would assign an IAM Role to the EC2 instance. Thus, they would be getting permissions from different IAM entities.

@JohnRotenstein I am providing same credentials to both of the environments i have them in my environment variables, and when I first faced this issue it asked me to put the credentials in ~/aws/. credentials folder ( in ec2) , everything was working fine before this on both of my environments ( local and ec2)

An Access Denied error is directly related to the permissions assigned to the IAM credentials being used. It's a permissions problem, not a code problem. To diagnose, you could run aws sts get-caller-identity on both machines and see what credentials it thinks it is using. You might find that it isn't using the ones you expect.

@JohnRotenstein I even tried hard coding the credentials inside of the interface still the same

@ShivrajThapliyal were you able to solve it?

@brohxa No I couldn't.
